# TinyMCE exec Command inside php loop

Tags: javascript, php, tinymce, href

Trying to get an href with TinyMCE command function working but no luck. I used double and single quotes as well. Here is the original code

```
echo "<a href="javascript:;" onclick="tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, document.getElementById('div_".$i."').innerHTML); 
            return false;">[Manage Marketing]</a>";
```

Comment: I fixed it. :) Just had to put \ infront of the double quotes inside echo " "

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent('');tinymce.execCommand('mceInsertContent',false, document.getElementById('div_".$i."').innerHTML); 
        return false;\">[Manage Marketing]</a>";
```